# How to interact with a specific email in outlook?

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I was trying to read the body of Emails I was receiving in Outlook, but I only could read the my emails from my first Email address. Is there a way to choose the Email address that should be read? Like for example the fouth email adress in my outlook account?

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
body = message.body
subject = message.subject
sender = message.sender

while message:
    print("Subject: " + subject
    + "\tSender: " + str(sender)
    + "\nBody: " + body
    + "\n"
    )
    message = messages.GetNext()
```

I already tried to give "Inbox" a second argument because I thought, that I could choose the email over that, but that only gave me errors.

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(4, 6)
```

So is there a clever and easy way to choose the email address you want to read?

Comment: Hi. I don't have Outlook, but web-searching for "outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)" returns quite a few results. Have you tried looking into that? Also, error messages usually are the only way to solve errors, so posting that output is also a good idea.

Comment: "outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)" refers to the folder I want to open (6 is my Inbox) like for example "outlook.GetDefaultFolder(3)"  refers to my Deleted Items.

Answer (score 0):

You can logon to a specified mail profile:
(example code taken from [Tim Golden's Python Stuff](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/read-my-outlook-inbox.html))

```
import win32com.client

session = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch ("MAPI.Session")

#
# Leave blank to be prompted for a session, or use
# your own profile name if not "Outlook". It is also
# possible to pull the default profile from the registry.
#
session.Logon ("Outlook")
messages = session.Inbox.Messages

#
# Although the inbox_messages collection can be accessed
# via getitem-style calls (inbox_messages[1] etc.) this
# is the recommended approach from Microsoft since the
# Inbox can mutate while you're iterating.
#
message = messages.GetFirst ()
while message:
  print message.Subject
  message = messages.GetNext ()
```

Comment: You have replaced "Outlook" by the name of you mail profile? Where do you get which error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DeliveryStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Account.DeliveryStore) property of the Account to get its inbox. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()
Dim ns As NameSpace
Set ns = Application.Session
Dim acc As Account
Dim f As Folder

For Each acc In ns.accounts
    MsgBox acc.UserName
    If acc = "text@outlook.com" Then
    Set f = acc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    MsgBox f.Items.count

End If
Next
End Sub
```

You can filter using acc = "text@outlook.com" or the acc.UserName property.

Comment: But that is VBA I was looking for something in Python.